# Creating variable in multiple dataframes with different number with R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have these two dataframes:

```
df1 <-data.frame(v1=c("a","b"),v2=c("c","d"))
df2 <-data.frame(v1=c("a","b"),v2=c("c","d"))
```

I want to do a loop that creates a new variable (v3) that concatenates variables v1 and v2 for each dataframe, something like this:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  df[[i]]$v3 <- paste(a[[i]]$v1,a[[i]]$v2) 
}
```

Thus, the final dataframe df1 would be:

| v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | ac |
| b | d | bd |

And for df2 would be:

| v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | ac |
| b | d | bd |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we need `assign` to update the original objects

```
for(obj in c("df1", "df2")) {
    tmp <- get(obj)
    tmp$v3 <- paste0(tmp$v1, tmp$v2)
    assign(obj, tmp)
}
```

-output

```
> df1
  v1 v2 v3
1  a  c ac
2  b  d bd
> df2
  v1 v2 v3
1  a  c ac
2  b  d bd
```

---

Or instead of creating/updating multiple objects, it may be done in a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")), 
    transform, v3 = paste0(v1, v2))
```

If needed to update the original objects, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop here at all - `paste` is vectorised:

```
df1$v3 <- paste0(df1$v1, df1$v2)
df2$v3 <- paste0(df2$v1, df2$v2)
```

If you had the `data.frame`s in a list, then you could just use a `for` loop to append the 3rd column:

```
l = list(
    df1 = data.frame(v1=c("a","b"),v2=c("c","d")),
    df2 = data.frame(v1=c("a","b"),v2=c("c","d"))
)

for(i in seq_along(l)){
    l[[i]]$v3 <- paste0(l[[i]]$v1, l[[i]]$v2)
}
l
```

Yields:

```
$df1
  v1 v2 v3
1  a  c ac
2  b  d bd

$df2
  v1 v2 v3
1  a  c ac
2  b  d bd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
lapply(c('df', 'df_1'), \(i) setDT(get(i)))
lapply(c('df', 'df_1'), \(i) get(i)[, v3 := paste0(v1,v2)])
```